# How to deal with masked shortened-urls?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, markdown

[Which style of Latin plurals should I use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/which-style-of-latin-plurals-should-i-use) vs. [Which style of Latin plurals should I use?](http://j.mp/g29nZW) – Spot the difference! 
The second one has a shortened url; I find this downright rude. 
 
What are your views on the usage of masked shortened-urls? 
Is it wrong to edit such content and replace the shortened url with the original one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using url shorteners should be reserved for contexts where you MUST use an url shortener:

- the URL is very strange and contains semi-illegal chars that are hard to link here
- you are using a limited input area where the URL is so long, it would prevent you from entering other meaningful text
- the markup does not allow presenting a `<a href="">friendly link title</a>`

None of that applies here, so I would say they should be **discouraged unless absolutely necessary**.